# Is there a C equivalent of C#'s decimal type?

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal

> In relation to: [Convert Decimal to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/convert-decimal-to-double)

Now, I got to many questions relating to C#'s floating-point type called `decimal` and I've seen its differences with both `float` and `double`, which got me thinking if there is an equivalent to this type in C.

In the question specified, I got an answer I want to convert to C:

```
double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;
double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000d;
```

Of course, the only change is the second line gone, but with the thing about the `decimal` type, I want to know it's C equivalent.

**Question:** What is the C equivalent of C#'s `decimal`?

Comment: There is no "decimal" equivalent in C. Often, a plain integer is used [scaled `100` (or more for error/rounding management) times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(computer_science)#Fractional_values_scaled_to_integers).

Comment: Some C implementations have decimal floating-point. While the C standard permits it for the types `float` and `double`, it is more common for an implementation to use binary for those and provide decimal as an extension. For example, [GCC has `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128` types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html). You may find performance is low compared to binary floating-point.

Comment: You can make your own so sort of.

Comment: hardware support for decimal floating-point is extremely rare at the moment, so performance would be not quite good. You should used [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) instead, i.e. scale the value by a power of 10 and do everything in integer

Answer (score 6):

C2X will standardize decimal floating point as `_DecimalN`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2573.pdf

In addition, [GCC implements decimal floating point](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html) as an extension; it currently supports 32-bit, 64-bit, and 128-bit decimal floats.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit: much of what I said below is just plain *wrong*, as pointed out by [phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/phuclv) in the comments. Even then, I think there's valuable information to be gained in reading that answer, so I'll leave it unedited below.

**So in short: yes, there *is* support for `Decimal` floating-point values and arithmetic in the standard C language. Just check out [phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/phuclv)'s comment and [S.S. Anne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10795151/s-s-anne)'s answer.**

---

In the C programming language, as others have commented, **there's no such thing as a `Decimal` type**, nor are there types implemented like it. The simplest type that is close to it would be `double`, which is implemented, most commonly, as an IEEE-754 compliant 64-bit floating-point type. It contains a 1-bit sign, an 11-bit exponent and a 52-bit mantissa/fraction. The following image represents it quite well(from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IEEE_754_Double_Floating_Point_Format.svg#/media/File:IEEE_754_Double_Floating_Point_Format.svg)):

[image: 64-bit double]

So you have the following format:

[image: 64-bit format]

A more detailed explanation can be read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), but you can see that the exponent part is a power of two, which means that there will be imprecisions when dealing with division and multiplication by ten. A simple explanation is because division by anything that isn't a power of two is sure to repeat digits indefinitely in base 2. Example: 1/10 = 0.1(in base 10) = 0.00011001100110011...(in base 2). And, because computers can't store an unlimited amount of zeroes, your operations will have to be truncated/approximated.

In the case of C#'s `Decimal`, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal__ctor_System_Int32___):

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.

**This last part is important, because instead of being a multiplication by a power of two, it is a division by a power of ten**. So you have the following format:

[image]

**Which, as you can clearly see, is a completely different implementation from above!**

For instance, if you wanted to divide by a power of 10, you could do that *exactly*, because that just involves increasing the exponent part(N). You have to be aware of the limitation of the numbers that can be represented by `Decimal`, though, which is at most a measly 7.922816251426434e+28, whereas `double` can go up to 1.79769e+308.

Given that there are no equivalents (yet) in C to `Decimal`, you may wonder "what do I do?". Well, it depends. First off, is it really important for you to use a `Decimal` type? Can't you use a `double`? To answer that question, it's helpful to know *why* that type was created in the first place. Again, from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors

And, just at the next phrase:

> The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding

So you shouldn't think of `Decimal` as having "infinite precision", just as being a more appropriate type for calculations that generally need to be made in the decimal system(such as financial ones, as stated above).

If you still want a `Decimal` data type in C, you'd have to work in developing a library to support addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc --- Because C doesn't support operator overloading. Also, it still wouldn't have hardware support(e.g. from the x64 instruction set), so all of your operations would be slower than those of `double`, for example. Finally, if you still want something that supports a `Decimal` in other languages(in your final question), you may look into [Decimal TR in C++](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf).

Comment: `there's no such thing as a Decimal type` this is completely wrong. C standard allows floating-point types to use any integer bases and it's possible for some implementations to set `FLT_RADIX == 10` and use some format similar to C#'s Decimal. `nor are there types implemented like it` this is also wrong. Compilers are allowed to have extensions that support additional decimal floating point types. C2X is going to have `_DecimalN` as mentioned above, although they may not be C#'s Decimal

Comment: @phuclv Well I just learned something today! Can you suggest an edit and add sources/references? I'll gladly add that to my answer.

Comment: You can find `FLT_RADIX` references in any C standards including the C2X draft link in S.S. Anne's answer. You can also read about `_DecimalN` in that link

Answer (score 1):

As other pointed out, there's nothing in C standard(s) such as .NET's decimal, but, if you're working on Windows and have the Windows SDK, it's defined:

[DECIMAL structure (wtypes.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ns-wtypes-decimal-r1)

> Represents a decimal data type that provides a sign and scale for a
> number (as in coordinates.)
>
> Decimal variables are stored as 96-bit (12-byte) unsigned integers
> scaled by a variable power of 10. The power of 10 scaling factor
> specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, and
> ranges from 0 to 28.

```
typedef struct tagDEC {
  USHORT wReserved;
  union {
    struct {
      BYTE scale;
      BYTE sign;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    USHORT signscale;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
  ULONG  Hi32;
  union {
    struct {
      ULONG Lo32;
      ULONG Mid32;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME2;
    ULONGLONG Lo64;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME2;
} DECIMAL;
```

[DECIMAL is used to represent an exact numeric value with a fixed precision and fixed scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wsp/60a4934f-5d45-4b5c-9c8c-81c1f5c331b2).

The origin of this type is Windows' COM/OLE automation (introduced for VB/VBA/Macros, etc. so, it predates .NET, which has very good COM automation support), documented here officially: [[MS-OAUT]: OLE Automation Protocol, 2.2.26 DECIMAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/b5493025-e447-4109-93a8-ac29c48d018d)

It's also one of the VARIANT type (VT_DECIMAL). In x86 architecture, it's size fits right in the VARIANT (16 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Decimal type in C# is used is used with precision of  28-29 digits and it has size of 16 bytes.There is not even a close equivalent in C to C#.In Java there is a BigDecimal data type that is closest to C# decimal data type.C# decimal gives you numbers like:

```
+/- someInteger / 10 ^ someExponent
```

where someInteger is a 96 bit unsigned integer and someExponent is an integer between 0 and 28.

[Is Java's BigDecimal the closest data type corresponding to C#'s Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017583/is-javas-bigdecimal-the-closest-data-type-corresponding-to-cs-decimal)

Comment: `biggest data type in C stores 8 bytes` this is **absolutely wrong**. C just specify the **minimum limits** as well as requiring `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`. There's nothing preventing an implementation making `int` a 256-bit type or more. [Why does the size of an int vary in some compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893712/995714), [What defines the size of a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56156513/995714), [Is the size of C “int” 2 bytes or 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438794/995714)

Comment: and C also doesn't specify that floating point types must be binary either. It's completely valid for a compiler to set `double` to something exactly the same as C#'s Decimal