# What's the C++ equivalent of C#'s decimal type?

Tags: c#, c++, decimal

I like `decimal` in many of my C# programs and I want to try it in other C languages.

I wrote this code in C#:

```
using System;

decimal get_pi();

int main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number ranging from 1-100: ");
    decimal num = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Algebraic Equivalent: ");
    if (num >= get_pi()) {
        Console.WriteLine("π");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
    // Currently updating the program for giving algebraic equivalents
}
```

And I want to rewrite it in C++.

I realized that in both C and C++, they have no exact equivalent to the `decimal` type, and best you can use is `double`, but the fact that there's actually a supported `decimal` type in C (based on [Is there a C equivalent of C#'s decimal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400149/is-there-a-c-equivalent-of-cs-decimal-type)), it got me curious if there is also an equivalent in C++.

Is there any C# `decimal` type equivalent in C++ or is `double` the best choice instead?

Comment: Then no, there is not a direct equivalent - depends on usage. A `long double` would be “closer”, depending on implementation. (That might be an extension..)

Comment: decimal in c# is a floating decimal rather than a floating binary type. Check if there is a floating decimal type in c++. That would likely be the equivalent.

Comment: Boost multiprecision has higher-precision floating point types you can use: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html

Comment: @janzen [C++ supports everything in C's math.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) including FLT_RADIX so it's possible for a compliant implementation to have decimal `float` and `double`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not, though I believe there's a proposal out there.

But if you navigate over to *IBM Fellow* [Mike Cowlishaw's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Cowlishaw) page *[General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/)*, you'll

- Learn more than you ever wanted to know about the topic — he pretty much wrote the IEEE 754 specification for decimal floating point — and
- Get a link to an [ANSI C implementation](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html) of it

For what it's worth, the .Net source code is open-source and on Github. If you wanted to port `System.Decimal` from C# to C++, you could start here:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.cs
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.DecCalc.cs

Answer (score 1):

C#'s `decimal` type is actually just a so called *arbitrary precision* float with the word *arbitrary* switched out with a fixed value, which can be looked up in its [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.cs) (already linked by [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565768/4850111)). It's 28 significant digits.

Arbitrary precision floats are not included in at least C++20's standard library, but there are quite a number of libraries out there, which include that functionality. C#'s `decimal` is also part of the .NET *library*, which is strictly speaking also a *library* and not part of the language itself (but very tightly coupled).

Examples for libraries supporting arbitrary precision floats for C++ include:

- GNU GMP https://gmplib.org/
- Boost's Multiprecision Library https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multiprecision/
- CLN's `long float` https://ginac.de/CLN/
- Henrik Vestermark's `float precision<N>` http://www.hvks.com/Numerical/arbitrary_precision.html <- *This one actually contains an example for printing out pi (to* `std::string`), *which seems to be what you're looking for*
- and many many more: [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)